# insert a string between two patterns

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed

I  would like to change file with name like:

```
d1-a2_A1_B1.txt
abcd_A90_B2.txt
```

where I want to insert `_FOO` in between first `_A[0-9]\+` and `_B[0-9]` so the file names becomes

```
d1-a2_A1_FOO_B1.txt
abcd_A90_FOO_B2.txt
```

But my regular expression doesnot work:

```
for f in $(ls); do mv $f \`echo $f | sed -e s/\(.*_A[0-9]\+\)\(_B[0-9].*\)/$1_FOO$2/\`; done
```

I tried with a single string:

```
echo abcd_A90_B2.txt | sed -e s/\(.*_A[0-9]\+\)\(_B[0-9].*\)/$1_FOO$2/
```

OK: this worked:

```
echo abcd_A90_B2.txt | sed -e 's/\(_A[0-9]\+\)\(_B[0-9]\)/\1_FOO\2/'
```

Answer (score 2):

- Add the `-r` option to `sed` (to get it to use extended regular expressions;
  it normally doesn't understand `+`).
- Put your `sed` script into quotes (preferably single quotes).
- Change `$1` and `$2` in your script to `\1` and `\2`:

  ```
  sed -re 's/(._A[0-9]+)(_B[0-9].)/\1_FOO\2/'
  ```

Also,

- For clarity, you might want to change `` `…` `` to `$(…)` —
  see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778),
  [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147838),
  and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104119) —
  i.e., handle the `echo | sed` the same way you handle the `ls`.
- It’s better to say `for f in *` (rather than `for f in $(ls)`).
- You should quote shell variable references (e.g., `echo "$f"`)
  unless you have a good reason not to,
  and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Comment: I have tried but didn't work: echo abcd_A90_B2.txt | sed -e 's/(._A[0-9]+)(_B[0-9].)/$1_FOO$2/'  that didn't change 
abcd_A90_B2.txt

Comment: OK, I revised my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using sed and other string manipulation by using `mmv`:

```
$ mmv -m -n  '*_A*_B*.txt' '#1_A#2_FOO_B#3.txt'
abcd_A90_B2.txt -> abcd_A90_FOO_B2.txt
d1-a2_A1_B1.txt -> d1-a2_A1_FOO_B1.txt
```

(Leave out the `-n` or replace it with `-v` to actually rename the files once you've confirmed all files are matched and renamed as you want.